# reledmac/reledpar: Placing the generated auxiliary / helper files in a seperate folder

Tags: auxiliary-files, reledmac, reledpar

When using the `reledmac`/`reledpar` packages a lot of auxiliary or helper files are generated (see screenshot, e. g. .1, .1R, .Aend, .eledsec1, ...).

## Screenshot

[image]

## Problem / Question

I will have a large document and these files make it a bit messy.

> Is there a way to put these files in a sub-folder, e. g. called temp?

## Code for the Screenshot Result

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Test
            \pend 
        \endnumbering           
    \end{Leftside}
    %
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Test
            \pend 
        \endnumbering   
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: no, there is now way. But please open an issue on github, will be quickly.

Comment: ps : you could also use the `noend` option and `noeledsec` option, if you not need the `eledxxx` command or endnotes.

Comment: @Maïeul Ok - I just created an Issue (#526) on github. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the package [author's comment](https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/526) on github my problem **cannot be solved** within the package.

> **Update 7th June 2016**
>
> See https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/526 New option `auxdir`
>   available (e. g. `\usepackage[auxdir=TempFolder]{reledmac}`)